# What does "extend to X linearly" mean?

Tags: normed-spaces

I'd ask someone to edit my question, I'm not sure if it's correctly spelled.

Let $X$ be a normed vector space with Hamel basis $\{e_n\}$,$n\in \mathbb{N}$
consistent in unit vectors $e_n$ and $Te_n=ne_n$
(here it comes) "**Extend T to all X linearly**".

Show:

$T$ is bounded $\Leftrightarrow$ X is finite dimensional.

What does "Extend T to all X linearly" mean?

How can i conclude something is finite dimensional?

Can you hint any useful theorem for this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It usually just means "suppose $T$ is linear". In other words
$$T(\sum_{\alpha} x_{\alpha}e_\alpha) = \sum_{\alpha}x_\alpha T(e_\alpha).$$
The key point is that defining how a linear map behaves on a basis defines how it behaves on the entire space.

Now, suppose that $T$ is bounded, so that $\|Tx\|\leq C\|x\|$ for some positive constant $C$. Note that $\|e_n\|=1$ for each $n$, so we have that
$$\|Te_n\| = \|ne_n\| = n\leq C.$$
In particular, $n$ can be no larger than $\lfloor C\rfloor$, so the Hamel basis can have no more than $\lfloor C\rfloor$ elements.

For the converse, suppose $X$ has an $m$-dimensional Hamel basis $\{e_1,\dotsc, e_m\}$. Then each $x\in X$ can be written as a finite linear combination of these elements: $x=x_1e_1+\dotsm x_me_m$. Using linearity, it won't be hard to show that $T$ is bounded with the constant $C$ depending on $m$. I'll leave the details to you, but it will be useful to keep in mind that every norm on a finite dimensional vector space is equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Any linear transformation is determined by its values on a basis. As $T$ is defined on $\left \{ e_n \right \}_{n\in \mathbb N}$, the natural thing to do is to define $T$ on all of $V$ by $Tv=T(\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_ie_i)\doteq \sum_{i=1}^{n}c_iT(e_i),$ for any vector $v\in V$.You can check that this definition makes $T$ linear on $V$.

Now, in your case, $T(e_n)=ne_n \,$so if $V$ is infinite dimensional then

$\left \{ e_n \right \}_n$ is infinite and each member satisfies $\left \| e_n \right \|=1$. Using the $\sup $ definition of the norm, we have $\left \| T \right \|\geq \left \| T(e_n) \right \|=n\left \| e_n \right \|=n$, which can be made arbitrarily large, since $V$ is infinite dimensional.

If $V$ is $n$-dimensional, it is not hard to show that $T$ is bounded, since if $\left \| v \right \|=1$ then $\left \| T(\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_ie_i) \right \|\leq n\sum^{n}_{i=1} \vert c_i\vert<\infty $

Comment: I'm lost in this:
what does this $||v||=1$ has to do in th end?